# How to do 2 dimensional str split

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a string looks like(Please notice I'm giving a range 1.1 to 1.3),

```
"1.1-1.3 ,1.5, 2.5"
```

I want a 2 dimensional array that looks like,

```
[1][1],
[1][2] , <== range is filled now
[1][3] ,
[1][5],
[2][5],
```

I'm not great with Python. I know there has to be a nicer way to do this with few lines of code. Can someone please help? I am using 3.4

Comment: What have attempted so far?

Answer (score 1):

Idea:

1. Remove all spaces: `'1.1-1.3 ,1.5, 2.5'`
2. Split the input with comma: `'1.1-1.3,1.5,2.5'`
3. Parse them into numbers or ranges: `[(1, 1, 1, 3), (1, 5), (2, 5)]`
4. Generate and append the data into a list: `[[1, 1], [1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 5], [2, 5]]`

Code:

```
import re

s = '1.1 -1.3 ,1.5, 2.5'
items = s.replace(' ', '').split(',')

result = []
for item in items:
    v = list(map(
        lambda x: int(x) if x else None,
        re.match(r'(\d+).(\d+)(?:-(\d+).(\d+))?', item).groups()
    ))
    if not v[2]:
        result.append(v[:2])
    else:
        result.extend([[v[0], i] for i in range(v[2], v[3] + 1)])

print(result)
```